# Can't get <div> to change color using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So, I've got a small website that I'm working on-- it's very simple, I'm just using it to EVENTUALLY play with C++ and Javascript COM interfaces and bitwise operators.

But I'm getting stuck on the simple stuff.

Here's my HTML, CSS, and jQuery code respectively (formatted for jsfiddle).

```
<title>Can you guess the combination?</title>
<body>
    <div>
        <label id="instructions">Guess the combination and you win!</label>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
</body>
```

---

```
.button {
    background-color:#0F0;
    width:3em;
    height:3em;
    display:table-cell;
    float:left;
    margin:0.5em;
}
#instructions {
    font-family:roboto;
    font-color:#bbbbb;
}
a {
    font-family:roboto;
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css("background", "#ddd");
    },

    function () {
        $(this).css("background", "#ccc");
    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwarner112/nu62L/) is a jsfiddle of what I have, where hovering over the boxes should cause them to change color. I can't get this example working. It's very simple, but I can't seem to tell what I've done.

Later I'll have more advanced features, but as it is I'm tired of staring at this myself.

Do you have any ideas, {StackOverflow Member}?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nu62L/1/   just include jquery

Comment: you had missed including a js library...possible a google hosted cdn

Answer (score 4):

Use css for this

```
.button {background-color: #ddd;}
.button:hover {background-color: #ccc;}
```

Comment: This is *a* solution, but the question was more about how to solve it using jQuery. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 2):

Updated JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nu62L/5/).

The problems were that jQuery wasn't included in the jsFiddle, there was no reason to have a `$('document').ready()`, and the correct CSS is `background-color`, not `background`

Code here

```
$(".button").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ddd");
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#ccc");
    }
);
```

Comment: `background` is shorthand property if you wanna write e.g. `background: #f5f5f5 url(../images/bg.png)` it's correct & valid.

Comment: And `$('document').ready()` is necessary because the jQuery is above the `<div>s` and I want it to load afterward, so it can include the loaded `<div>s`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concentrate to top-left of JS Fiddle and change the value of the first drop down as below image:

[image: JS Fiddle Screen Shot]

Comment: This got it working on jsfiddle, which means my in-house solution is simply lacking jQuery interpretation. Now I need to make it work for Javascript.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to figure out the solution, which will be submitted and this turned into a community post.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is working correctly 
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css("background", "#ddd");
    },

    function () {
        $(this).css("background", "#ccc");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.button {
    background-color:#0F0;
    width:3em;
    height:3em;
    display:table-cell;
    float:left;
    margin:0.5em;
}
#instructions {
    font-family:roboto;
    font-color:#bbbbb;
}
a {
    font-family:roboto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label id="instructions">Guess the combination and you win!</label>
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to parts of your answer I was able to form my own. Please view my community wiki answer to see what my final solution was.

Answer (score 0):

The correct CSS is `color`, not `font-color`.

To change background, use `background-color`.

Comment: That's not the question and this should be a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be multi-fold.

First,
I did not have `jQuery` included in the project. I was running a script written in jQuery but without pre-loading that which lets the Javascript interpreter handle jQuery.

To amend this, just above the `<script>` that includes my jQuery work, I included this:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Now the Javascript engine can handle jQuery commands.

Next, I was mis-labelling one of the CSS properties. Where in my `jQuery` script I had written:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#ddd");
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#ccc");
        }
    );
});
```

I should have instead written:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ddd");
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ccc");
        }
    );
});
```

(I had missed that `background` is not a CSS property, and what I meant was `background-color`)

A note when writing your own jQuery code: If your `<script>` tag is *before* your actual web code, make sure that the code inside the script is nested inside the line:

```
$(document).ready(x)
```

Because without that, the Javascript engine will execute operations on HTML objects that don't exist yet; With this line however, it will wait until all the HTML objects are loaded and modifiable.